# Typecasting a template functions return value

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function . This function returns the same template type . Ex: It takes T type variable and return the T type variable. Now can I cast the return type T variable using static cast to Uint32.Will I get any errors

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see if you get any errors?

Answer (score 7):

From what I understand you have a function that looks like

```
template <class T>
T noop (T a) {
  return a;
}
```

and you want to cast the result of it

```
uint32 i = static_cast<uint32>(noop(val));
```

This will succeed if `val` is of a type that can be cast to uint32 and fail if it isn't.

```
uint32 i = static_cast<uint32>(noop(uint32(0))); // ok
uint32 i = static_cast<uint32>(noop("asdf")); // not-ok
```